# Missing data are biasing sample

Tags: missing-data, bias, survey-sampling

I'm working with a sample of 1,222 survey respondents. Given the length of the survey, many respondents did not complete every question.

After removing observations with missing data, I am left with 632 observations.

I don't believe a t-test would be good at identifying whether the 632 respondents are a biased sample, because very few variables are available for all 1,222 respondents.

Would running propensity scoring matching on an outcome variable "missing", with a dummy = 1 if an observations is in the final sample (0 if no), be an appropriate way to check if the final sample suffers from selection bias?

Thanks for your help!